# Remove duplicate records by comparing two data tables in c#

Tags: c#, filter, datatable, copy

I have two data tables. One have all records and other data table have only few records. I have to insert records in third table which are not in second table but want to do it only with c# not linq.I tried with for and foreach loop but not getting exact.

Comment: you will probably need to merge the two datatables into 1 datatable then iterate over it to filter out duplicates

Comment: first data table have all records and second table have some records from first data table. Now third data table should have records which are not in second table

Comment: The way I understand is that DataTable A is complete, DataTable B  is contains records that A might already have. I think you can use Find() of the DataRowCollection to check if a row in DataTable B is already in A then add the row in third table if its not yet there, here's link for your reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks let me try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would not recommend to do this, like ever. Foreach within foreach is a very bad idea, there are better solutions (like merging) out there. Try consider using linq. But you could try something like

```
foreach (datarow dr1 in datatable1)
{
    bool add = true;

    foreach (datarow dr2 in datatable2)
    {
         // Make sure the itemarray[x] is the proper indetifier
         if (dr2.itemarray[0].toString() == dr1.itemarray[0])
         {
             add = false;
             break;
         }
    }
    if (add)
    {
        // add record to datatable3
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me doing same through linq ??